# How to replace all occurrences in 1 file with sed?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I need to replace all occurrences and write back to the same file

I tried:

```
sed 's/one/two/g' file.txt
```

this print out but does not write to file

I also tried

```
sed 's/one/two/g' file.txt>file.txt
```

This results in empty file

```
sed -i 's/one/two/g' file.txt
```

gives error: `sed: 1: "file.txt": invalid command code f`

Any idea?

Answer (score 25):

For Mac: Use `-i.bak` to add a backup file

```
sed -i.bak 's/one/two/g' file.txt
```

Or

```
sed -i '' 's/one/two/g' file.txt
```

For Linux:
Use `sed -i` on to do infile substitution

```
sed -i 's/one/two/g' file.txt
```

You can also do something like below using a tmp file:

```
sed 's/one/two/g' file.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt file.txt
```

Comment: mac7:~ $ sed -i 's/one/two/g' file.txt
sed: 1: "file.txt": invalid command code f

Comment: @user300675 You can give -i.bak on Mac

Comment: Another way would be to add `''` after -i